# Summation coincides with integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, continuity

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a<b$.
Then let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the interval $[a,b]$.
Under what conditions the following property is satisfied :

$$\sum^{b}_{k=a} f(k) = \int^{b}_{a}f(t)dt$$

Comment: I'm not sure what conditions (if there are any) where this property is satisfied, but a couple examples include $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ with $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$ and $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I mean, if we use the counting measure...

Comment: A sort of trivial sufficient (though not at all necessary) condition is if the function is constant on each integral interval i.e. it is piecewise defined at each integer and is constant on each piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula),
$$  \sum_{i=m}^n f(i) =
    \int^n_m f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{f(n) + f(m)}{2} +
    \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \left( f^{(2k - 1)}(n) - f^{(2k - 1)}(m) \right) - (-1)^{p} \int_m^n f^{(p)}(x)\frac{P_p(x)}{p!} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
where

- $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers (per  ISO 80000-2, the nonnegative integers),
- $p$ is a positive integer,
- $f$ is a $p$-times [continuously differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuously_differentiable) on $[m,n]$ function that is either real-valued or complex-valued,
- $B_{2k}$ are [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers) (There are two conventions for Bernoulli numbers.  Since we only use the even index Bernoulli numbers, the two conventions coincide.), and
- and $P_p$ is a [periodized Bernoulli polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Periodic_Bernoulli_polynomials).

So, for such a collection of $f$, $m$, $n$, and $p$, the answer to your question is "When everything after the first '$+$' happens to be zero (taken together)."

For instance, of $f$ is once continuously differentiable on $[m,n]$, then we may take $p = 1$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=m}^n f(i) &- \int^n_m f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \frac{f(m) + f(n)}{2} + \int_m^n f'(x) P_1(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \frac{f(m) + f(n)}{2} + \int_m^n f'(x) B_1(x - \lfloor x \rfloor) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \frac{f(m) + f(n)}{2} + \int_m^n f'(x) \left( (x - \lfloor x \rfloor) - \frac{1}{2} \right) \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
and all we require is that the object on the right is $0$.

We can get an immediately example : $f(x) = x$ for $m = -n$.  The first term is zero (because of the symmetric choice of $m$ and $n$) and the integral is zero because $f'(x) = 1$ and the integral of $P_1(x)$ is zero on $[j,j+1]$ for any integer $j$.  By a similar argument, $f(x) = -x$ for a similar choice of $m$.

Since $P_1$ is periodic, we should be able to find a periodic $f'$ that works.  For instance, $f'(x) = \sin^2(2\pi x)$ makes the integral zero (again by making it zero on every $[j,j+1]$ for any integer $j$).  Then we need to select $C$, $m$ and $n$ such that
$$  f(x) = \int \sin^2(2\pi x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{\sin(4\pi x)}{8\pi} + C  $$
gives zero in the first term.  A choice is $m = -n$ and $C = 0$, but there are others, for instance any $C$, $m$, and $n$ satisfying $m+4C+n = 0$ work.  (So here are infinitely many examples of the sum and the integral being equal for this one choice of $f'$.)

If we keep playing around with periodic $f$s that make the integral zero and finding resulting constraints on the constant of integration (to go from $f'$ to $f$) and $m$ and $n$, we could find many more infinite families of examples.

We could then start tailoring non-periodic $f'$s that still make the integral zero and then solve for $m$, $n$ and constant of integration triples that make the sum equal the integral.

Answer (score 2):

I will be very surprised if there is an easy and useful criterion for this. Indeed, for *any* continuous function $f$, we can always modify $f$ on a small interval avoiding integer points such that the equality becomes true.

But if $a = -\infty$ and/or $b=+\infty$ are allowed, here are some striking examples:

1. Defining $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ with $\operatorname{sinc}(0) = 1$, then $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and
   $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(n) = \pi = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$
   (This is @Ty.'s example.)
2. Extending the factorial to non-integral arguments by letting $x! = \Gamma(x+1)$ and defining the binomial coefficients accordingly, we have
   $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{n} = 2^{\alpha} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
   for any $\alpha \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary condition **valid just for an always positive** function is that it has to be not decreasing.

Indeed, If this happens :

$$\:\forall n \in [a,b]  :f(n)>\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx \implies \sum_{k=a}^{b} f(k) > \int_a^{b+1}f(x)dx > \int_a^bf(x)dx$$

An equivalent condition can be stated for an always negative function.